# Не работает цикл по выводу изображений из базы данных HTTP 500

Tags: php, mysql, изображения, циклы, phpmyadmin

Беру значения из таблицы user где login равно кук файлу логина, превращаю в массив. Беру из него значение Ppage(строка) и разбиваю её на массив затем беру из таблицы photo данные где id равно массиву Ppage, кодирую и вывожу значение img. Ошибка HTTP 500

```
<?php
  $mysql = new mysqli('localhost', 'root', 'root', 'register');
  $cook = $_COOKIE['login'];
  $query = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `user` WHERE `login` = $cook");
  while($row = $query->fetch_assoc()){
    $Ppage = str_split($row['Ppage']);
    while($2row = $Ppage) {
    $dm = $mysql->query("SELECT * FROM `photo` WHERE `id`=$2row");
    $show_img = base64_encode($dm['img']);?>
    <img src="data:image/jpeg;base64, <?=$show_img ?>" alt="">
  <?php } } ?>
```

Comment: Пожалуйста, уточните вашу конкретную проблему или приведите более подробную информацию о том, что именно вам нужно. В текущем виде сложно понять, что именно вы спрашиваете.

Comment: ошибка 500 может быть по многим причинам. Смотрите логи и узнавайте конкретную проблему

Comment: для начала  у вас сам запрос не выполняется, ибо `$cook`, вероятно, ожидается строкой и должен быть заключен в кавычки. Но также следует задуматься, что будет, если пользователь подправит куки и впишет туда какое-нить `or id=1 order by id limit 1 #`. Потом почитать про сессии и не хранить логину в куки, или хоть шифровать их что ли. Затем еще озадачится тем, можно ли выполнять запросы не в цикле а сразу получить данные для всех строк, используя join. Про использование `select *` тоже подумать, особенно если у вас не одно поле с картинками. да и в целом о том стоит ли хранить картинку в таблице

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как и какими средствами находить ошибки в PHP коде?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/701142/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%b0%d0%ba%d0%b8%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d1%81%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d1%81%d1%82%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%b8-%d0%bd%d0%b0%d1%85%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%be%d1%88%d0%b8%d0%b1%d0%ba%d0%b8-%d0%b2-php-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%b4%d0%b5)

Comment: это не относится к проблеме, скорее всего вы её сами решите, если включите отображение ошибок (ссылка выше), но на будущее, никогда не вставляйте сырые данные запроса в sql - запрос, это потенциальная sql - иньекция (почитать можно тут https://www.php.net/manual/ru/security.database.sql-injection.php)

Comment: Нельзя называть переменные `$2row`